# Finding the currently selected tab of Ttk Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have a Ttk Notebook widget containing 8 Frames - so, 8 tabs. Each frame contains a Text widget. I have a button outside the Notebook widget, and I want to insert text into the current tabs Text widget when this button is pressed.

This would seem to require working out which widget in the Notebook is currently selected, but I can't seem to find how to do this. How would I find the currently selected tab?

Alternatively, how can I implement what I want to?

If it helps, here's the code for my notebook:

```
self.nb = Notebook(master)
self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand='yes', padx=10, pady=10)
self.frames = []
self.texts = []
for i in xrange(8):
  self.frames.append(Frame())
  self.nb.add(self.frames[i])
  self.texts.append(Text(self.frames[i]))
  self.texts[i].pack(fill='both')
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can retrieve the selected tab through `select` method. However, this method returns a tab_id which is not much useful as is. `index` convert it to the number of the selected tab.

```
>>> nb.select()
'.4299842480.4300630784'
>>> nb.index(nb.select())
2
```

Note that you coud also get more information about the selected tab using `tab`

```
>>> nb.tab(nb.select(), "text")
'mytab2'
```

You might look at Notebook reference documentation : http://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#notebook

Comment: Ahhh, exactly what I wanted! I was having trouble sifting through the documentation, so I must have missed this. But yes, this is perfect.

Answer (score 15):

You can get currently selected tab using the `"current"` keyword:

```
noteBook.index("current")
```

Check this website:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#tab-identifiers
24.2.5.3. Tab Identifiers

Answer (score 11):

There are two simple ways to see which tab is selected:

```
nb.select()  # returns the Tab NAME (string) of the current selection
```

and

```
nb.index('current') # returns the Tab INDEX (number) of the current selection
```

The `.select()` method can also be used to select which tab is currently active, via `nb.select(tabId)`.  Without the arg, it returns the tabId (in "name" form) of the current selection.

The `.index(tabId)` converts a tabId into a numerical index. It also can take the string "end" which will return the number of tabs. So, `nb.index(tkinter.END)` is like a `len()` method for a notebook widget.

When there are no tabs, `.select()` returns an empty string, but `.index('current')` throws an exception. So, if you want the index, I would say

```
if nb.select():
    idx = nb.index('current')
```

is the best way to go.

In your particular case, you would probably want to grab the current notebook tab name and then convert that name into the actual child text widget, via the `nametowidget()` method, for manipulation. So...

```
tabName = notebook.select()
if tabName:
    textWidget = notebook.nametowidget(tabName) # here, 'notebook' could be any widget
    textWidget.insert(pos, text, tags)
```

The `nametowidget(name)` method maps a Tkinter name to the actual widget. It is a method callable by any actual widget.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a expert at all but hope i can help with some "fresh eyes".
I imagine it could be something involving

```
def buttonclick():
      somevariablename = focus_get()
      #Print your text into the somevariable notebook could be
      #something like(not sure about the syntax):
      focusednotebook = somevariablename
      focusednotebook.insert('1.0', 'your text here')

yourbutton = Button(parent, text = "button name", command = buttonclick)
yourbutton.pack()
```

Hope it works or get you in the right direction.

Please feel free to edit as I am fairly new here amd with python :-)

Comment: Ahhh, yes, this is pretty similar to what I ended up using. Not quite what I'm looking for, but it does what I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting the tageted tab in tk.Notebook it's easy** all you have to do is to use the notebook object and target the index of the current tab. This can be done as follows

```
 # creating a notebook object
 notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, height=height, width=width, padding=20)

 # Adding tabs
 notebook.add(bin_tab, text="Binary Conversion")
 notebook.add(oct_tab, text="Octal Conversion")
 notebook.add(hex_tab, text="Hexadecimal Conversion")

 print(notebook.index("current")) # returns 0, 1, 2depending on how many tabs you have in my case i have 3 which means index from 0 to 2
```