# How to detect the current tab in notebook tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

How to detect which tab is currently in use in tkinter notebook widget? I am created a tabbed text editor, and I want to detect the current tab. I have tried the `grab_current` method, but it is not working.

Please help!

Comment: The tab ID `"current"` refers to the current selected tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the currently selected tab of Ttk Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000944/finding-the-currently-selected-tab-of-ttk-notebook)